# Is there any difference, from Google's point of view, on the method used for a 301 redirect?

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a website with an extremely good Google rank for it's particular niche. I've rebranded and need to redirect to a new URL. In the eyes of Google, what's the difference, if any, between the following two redirects in the context of preserving my site ranking:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
Rewriterule ^$ http://www.website.com/ [r=301,nc]
```

and...

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.website.com/
```

Comment: The way that you will do the 301 redirect does not play any role for the Google. Actually it does not see your configuration file. What it is important is to send the 301 headers with the new location on each old url and not just the home page. For example if you have 10 pages on the old website, make sure that these all pages are redirected to the new 10 pages. Your configuration does not redirect the whole domain, just the homepage. Take a look [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13001256/3330952)

Comment: @krokola: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

The way that you will do the 301 redirect does not play any role for the Google. Actually it does not see your configuration file.

What it is important is to send the 301 headers with the new location on each old url and not just the home page. For example if you have 10 pages on the old website, make sure that these all pages are redirected to the new 10 pages.

Your configuration does not redirect the whole domain, just the homepage. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13001256/3330952)